# undefined reference to `_imp__InitCommonControls@0'

Tags: wxwidgets

При линковке проекта с использованием wxWidgets с Cmake выдает

> undefined reference to `_imp__InitCommonControls@0'

Собирается это на Ubuntu под Windows используя mingw32-w64, wxWidgets предварительно собран mingw'ом и лежит по пути /usr/lib/wx-3.1-win

Оттуда напрямую и беру библиотеки core и base, но каким-то чудным образом из

> libwx_mswu_core-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a(corelib_msw_app.o)

жалуется, что нет ссылки на функцию (то есть библиотека с ее реализацией не подключена), и учитывая это подключаю libcomctl32.a

Содержимое Cmake следующее

```
include_directories(/usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-static-3.1 /usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/include/wx-3.1)
add_executable (welcome ${src}) #${core_src})


target_link_libraries(welcome  /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libcomctl32.a
                                            /usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwx_mswu_core-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a
                                           /usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a
                                              )
```

Но в итоге имею все те же сотни undefined reference. Как это исправить и почему если для `_imp__InitCommonControls@0` подключена библиотека, то ошибка остается?

UPD:

В библиотеке есть такая функция:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _imp__InitCommonControls@0 и _imp__InitCommonControls - разные символы. Я бы посмотрел через nm какой символ нужен в проблемном объектнике и какой есть в подсовываемой либе. Ну и попутно поискал бы либу с нужным символом. Но почему оно так сказать не смогу...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов В библиотеке есть такая функция, и она подключена (добавил скрин)

Comment: Перенес core и baseu на первое место, теперь не жалуется на функции из тех либ, которые подключены, получается размещать их нужно так, чтобы первыми были те библиотеки, которые используют следующие?

Comment: Очень вероятно что порядок имеет значение. Кто-то мне тут говорил про cygwin что там так. Но в mingw и cygwin я сам разбираюсь не очень...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При подключении библиотек важно сначала подключить библиотеки `libwx_...` а следом за ними `libcomctl32.a` и прочие.

Получилось, что для wx нужны библиотеки:

```
/usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwx_mswu_core-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a
/usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwx_baseu-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a
/usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwxpng-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a
/usr/lib/wx-3.1-win/lib/libwxzlib-3.1-i686-w64-mingw32.a


libmingw32.a                         
libcomctl32.a                          
libcomdlg32.a                                               
libole32.a                    
liboleaut32.a
libshlwapi.a
libuuid.a
libversion.a
libwinspool.a
libgdi32.a
```